# Error: No NgModule metadata found for 'undefined' in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular

Please find my code below, started facing this issue when I added below line

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { HTTPUserService } from "./app.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [HTTPUserService]
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!';
  getData:string;

  constructor(private _httpService:HTTPUserService){}

  onGet() {
    this._httpService.getUserData()
        .subscribe(
            data => this.getData = data,
            error => alert(error),
            () => console.log("Finished!")
        );
  }
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Comment: May I ask you why would you need to add this line there?

Comment: I just want to bootstrap my App and this is the solution I found.

Comment: you probably need to import `AppModule` into the file that has `platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);`

Comment: I already have with 'import { AppModule } from './app.module';' this line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why are you bootstraping the application in the component? Do that in an external file. Normally this is done in a `main.ts` file, that only knows the existence of the AppModule and nothing else

Comment: Error did go away on moving bootStrapModule code to app.module.ts and now it loads fine but component is still not bootStrapped.

Comment: @JaspreetSingh You probably have a main.ts file there, move the bootstrapping there. That or change your config to point to that the bootstrapping should be found from the app.module.ts file. ...